# how can you extract values from a python list that match a phrase using indexing to be put into another array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, indexing

I am currently working on an optimization that works for any size n where the network transportation is names with the convention 'x_i_j' where i is the sending node and j is the receiving node.

I have a list called x that contains all the relevant node names.

using

```
x =['x_%d_%d'%(i,j) for i in range(dims+2) for j in range(dims+2) if (i,j) in costs]
```

n is the number of points im interested in and dims=n*2

I am writing a constrain that is going to be a a n by 2 array where the first row has the 'x_i_j' values that i need to filter from the list given a criteria.

my code for my starting array works fine

```
start_constraint = [[x[i] for i in range(numvars)  if 'x_%d' %(dims) in x[i] ], [1 for i in range(numvars)  if 'x_%d' %(dims) in x[i]]]

output:
[['x_6_0', 'x_6_1', 'x_6_2'], [1, 1, 1]]
```

for my ending array
I am trying to extract the entities that are 'x_i_7'

I am currently trying it this way.

```
end_constraint = [[x[i] for i in range(numvars)  if 'x_%d_%d' %(i,dims+1) in x[i] ], [1 for i in range(numvars)  if 'x_%d_%d' %(i,dims+1) in x[i]]]

output: 
[[], []]
```

if i put values in for %(i,dims+1) such as %(4,7), the code will put that one value in.

How can I make this work using indexing and looping?

Comment: Do you have sample input and expected output to share?

Comment: `x = ['x_0_3', 'x_1_4', 'x_2_5', 'x_3_1', 'x_3_2', 'x_3_7', 'x_4_0', 'x_4_2', 'x_4_7', 'x_5_0', 'x_5_1', 'x_5_7', 'x_6_0', 'x_6_1', 'x_6_2'] ` and for the output of end_constraint is want `end_constraint = [['x_3_7', 'x_4_7', 'x_5_7'],[1,1,1]]`   also n=3 and dims = 6 for this scenario and numbers = 15